# In Excel VBA, how to count the number of rows between two tables?

Tags: vba, excel

I have two tables, the number of rows between these two tables varies. How do I identify the number of rows that exist between two tables?

Comment: Good question :) maybe if you share more data, like your code attempts and screenshots of your tables we can help.

Comment: @ShaiRado is absolutely right. What do you mean by "rows" between two tables? How about "columns" between two tables? What is a "table" to you? Are you using `ListObjects` or do you consider an "empty" row as a separator between two tables? Does that mean that there is no table with (possibly) empty records? If so, what is an "empty" row (no data at all in the entire row or only up to a particular column)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean cumulatively or separately?

**Separately**:
Select a cell anywhere in a table and it's:

```
Activecell.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
```

Cumulatively i'd need more info like table names or ranges etc..

Answer (score 0):

should you deal with two `ListObject` Tables and want to know rows distance between their defined ranges then you can use:

```
Function RowsBetweenTables(Table1 As ListObject, Table2 As ListObject) As Long
    Dim tempLong As Long

    If Intersect(Table1.Range.EntireRow, Table2.Range.EntireRow) Is Nothing Then
        tempLong = Table2.Range.Rows(1).Row - Table1.Range.Rows(Table1.Range.Rows.Count).Row - 1
        Select Case tempLong
            Case 0
                RowsBetweenTables = 0
            Case Is < 0
                RowsBetweenTables = Table1.Range.Rows(1).Row - Table2.Range.Rows(Table2.Range.Rows.Count).Row - 1
            Case Is > 0
                RowsBetweenTables = tempLong
        End Select
    Else
        RowsBetweenTables = -1
    End If
End Function
```

to be exploited as:

```
Sub main()
    Dim Table1 As ListObject, Table2 As ListObject
    Dim nRows As Long

    With Worksheets("Tables") '<--| change "Tables" with your actual sheet with tables name
        Set Table1 = .ListObjects("Table1") '<--| change "Table1" with your actual first table name
        Set Table2 = .ListObjects("Table2") '<--| change "Table1" with your actual second table name
    End With

    nRows = RowsBetweenTables(Table1, Table2)
    If nRows >= 0 Then
        MsgBox "there are " & nRows & " rows between tables"
    Else
        MsgBox "no rows between tables!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Jeevan: did you get through it?

Comment: @Jeevan: it'd be nice of you to give feedbakcs to people trying and help you